# Small JS Type Error (Not a Function) within switch

Tags: javascript, dom, switch-statement

My code returns an error on `document.getElementById('markOne').addClass('remview')` which is obviously not a `function`.
Why is this happening and how else can I add a class to my DOM element from within a `switch` condition?

```
var q = 0;
var sq = {};
sq.e = document.getElementById("main-container");
if (sq.e.addEventListener) {
  sq.e.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);
  sq.e.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelHandler, false);
} else sq.e.attachEvent("onmousewheel", MouseWheelHandler);

function MouseWheelHandler(e) {
  var e = window.event || e;
  var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
  q = q + delta;
  if (q == -2) {
    q = -1;
  } else if (q == 1) {
    q = 0;
  }
  switch (q) {
    case 0:
      break;
    case -1:
      document.getElementById('markOne').addClass('remview');
      break;
  }
  console.log(delta)
  console.log(q)
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a single class:

```
document.getElementById('markOne').className += ' remview';
```

Replace all existing classes:

```
document.getElementById('markOne').className = 'remview';
```

Add multiple classes (by passing a space-delimited list):

```
document.getElementById('markOne').className += ' remview other stuff'
```

Comment: Looks to me like those two lines are the same?

Comment: Also, you should probably write `document.getElementById('markOne').className += ' remview'`, so that `<div class="cool">` doesn't become `<div class="coolremview">`.

Comment: @Matías: You do know that your most recent edit makes example #3 incorrect; the space is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
   document.getElementById('markOne').classList.add('remview');
```

Comment: You might want to mention that this won't work for older browsers.

Comment: @gyre Thanks for heads up, it's not supported on IE9 and lower versions. If older browsers support is needed then I suggest using approach from other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just get rid of the switch condition?
I mean, all you are doing is checking if the `q` variable is equal to `-1` then adding a class to your element if it is, right?
If so you could just get rid of your switch condition.
Plus if you did that you would literally getting rid of ~4-5 lines of *"unnecessary"* code, and while it might not seem like much at the moment, tidying up and / or getting rid of 4-5 lines of code every once in a while can really make a **big difference** in the long run.

Here is your code with the switch statement removed and replaced with a if condition, also I've taken the liberty of tiding up your code:

```
var q = 0;
var sq = {};
sq.e = document.getElementById("main-container");
if (sq.e.addEventListener) {
  sq.e.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);
  sq.e.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelHandler, false);
} else sq.e.attachEvent("onmousewheel", MouseWheelHandler);

function MouseWheelHandler(e) {
  var e = window.event || e;
  var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
  q = q + delta;
  if (q == -2) {
    q = -1;
  } else if (q == 1) {
    q = 0;
  }
  // check if "q" IS NOT equal to "0" and that "q" IS EQUAL to "-1"
  if (q !== 0 && q === -1) {
    document.getElementById('markOne').addClass('remview');
  }
  console.log(delta)
  console.log(q)
  return false;
}
```

Good luck and all the best.